# Superscript in Label Xamarin Forms

Tags: sql-server-2008, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am displaying data in Label, data has some superscript text as `3x10⁹`. How can I display it correctly? What should be stored in a SQL Server database?

Comment: If the data is numeric to start with, just store it that way, 3000000000, you can create a IValueConverter that displays it with an exponent, otherwise just store it as a unicode string....

Comment: I am trying to store `3x10U+2079` in database but when we get the value and display. it shows as 3x10U+2079 same.

Comment: If you want to store it in a 8bit/char-based string, then `3x10\u2079`, otherwise use just use an NVarchar and store it as `3x10⁹`

Comment: Both are not working Using NVarchar and storing as  `3x10⁹` shows  `3x10?`and storing as `3x10\u2079` shows 3x10\u2079

Comment: Either way works fine for me on iOS and Android...

Comment: i got the solution I have to store it as `'3x10'+NCHAR(0x2079)'` in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Data should be stored in the database as the exact value and when you display the value, you can display in whatever format you want. tomorrow, there could be another application, which wants to display data as it is. data should be agnostic of the applications using the data.

I would suggest to store this big value in the BigInt datatype in SQL Server.
[BigInt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> bigint    -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)    8 Bytes